# Issue reporting in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geoprocessing, debugging, log

I've had an issue with the Processing plugin over that last few days. QGIS
has been really slow to start (about 15 minutes in some cases) and I then
get a message that says "Plugin Processing: the plugin will be disabled
because it crashed QGIS during last startup.

Please report and issue and
re-enable the plugin when the problem has been resolved"

Can anyone tell me how I report the issue? What logs I need, where do I
find them and who do I send them to?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS has a page [Bug/Issues Page](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html).

> QGIS is a largely volunteer driven project, and is the work of a dedicated team of developers, documenters, translators and supporters. Despite the efforts of the team to release QGIS without bugs, there may remain some bugs. If you find a bug or want new features to be added, please report it!

Plugin bugs

> Plugin bugs must be opened in their respective bug tracking system. Check first if the plugin is listed in the plugin overview. If so, click on the plugin name then click “New issue”.
>
> Most of the plugins are published in the official QGIS Plugins repository. If the plugin is available, you’ll find in its presentation a link to its bug tracker. Otherwise, consult the plugin documentation to find the address of the relevant bug tracking system or a developer to contact.

I would also keep in mind:

> Before filing an issue, review the currently open issues to make sure that you aren’t creating a duplicate. If you have additional information on an issue, you can add it to the existing ticket. Third party plugins might also cause problems. If you have installed any, you should also verify that the problem is still reproducible without them. Please don’t report multiple unrelated bugs in a single bug report.

In Linux, you can create a backtrace

> Creating a backtrace
>
> If you have a crash it might be useful to include a backtrace as the bug might be not reproducible on another machine.
>
> On Linux QGIS automatically tries to use gdb to connect to the crashing process to produce a backtrace. But some distributions disable the possiblity to connect debuggers to a running processes.

Log output on Windows

> The nightly build in OSGeo4W (package qgis-dev) is built with debugging output, that you can view with DebugView. If the problem is not easy to reproduce the output might shed some light about where QGIS crashes.

Comment: #whyzar, thanks. Your answer tells me where to record the bug. There were three questions is all. I still need to know where to know what logs I need and where to find those log files that will describe the issue that I want to flag.

Comment: @Johanna if you read the middle portion of the link I provided, you will see the part of creating a backtrace for Linux or producing a log for Windows. I'll update my post as well, quoting those sections.

Comment: If I was at home and had full admin rights to my PC I would have installed using OSGeo and would be able to follow the instructions. The sad thing is that I am at work and severely curtailed in the permissions that I have and therefore restricted in what I can do. Are there methods available to those of us in this situation?

Comment: I know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I find this happens sometimes if I launch QGIS twice by mistake (easily done in Ubuntu). Sometimes I launch QGIS and nothing seems to happen, so I try launching it again. The two copies of QGIS step on each others toes, which will give you that error message.